# How to convert image to binary string using php and file upload?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, upload, binary-image

I am trying to convert image in binary data but not getting solution in php.
please help

Trying to achieve something like this url.
https://www.dcode.fr/binary-image

1 . upload image and convert.
2 . This will convert my image to binary 0 and 1 format.
Same thing trying to do in php with simple upload form.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why should you convert to binary? Will this be good?

Comment: include your code and any error msgs in your question,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of [upload image tutorials](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=upload%20image%20php) on the interwebs, so ill leave you to figure that one out.

For converting an image to *binary*. You essentially loop over the image and look at each pixel then based upon its color you output a 1 or a 0.

```
function img_to_bin($file, $scale = 100, $fudge = 0) {

    if (!is_int($scale)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Scale argument invalid expecting int, got: '.gettype($scale));
    }

    $info = getimagesize($file);
    $mime = $info['mime'];

    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image_create = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            $image_create = 'imagecreatefrompng';
            break;

        case 'image/gif':
            $image_create = 'imagecreatefromgif';
            break;

        default: 
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Unsupported image type: '.$mime);
    }

    $return = null;

    $img = $image_create($file);
    $img = imagescale($img, $scale, $scale);

    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesy($img);

    for ($y=0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        $line = [];
        for ($x=0; $x < $width; $x++) {
            // get current pixel colour
            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8 ) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $pixel = ($r + $g + $b)/3;

            // value above 0(white) is 1 
            if ($pixel > $fudge) {
                $line[] = "1";
            } else {
                $line[] = "0";
            }
        }

        $return .= implode('', $line).PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $return;
}

echo img_to_bin("./face.png", 50).PHP_EOL;
```

So for an image like:

[image]

Will output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000
00000000000000000011111111111111100000000000000000
00000000000000011111111111111111111100000000000000
00000000000000111111111111111111111110000000000000
00000000000011111111111111111111111111100000000000
00000000000111111111111111111111111111110000000000
00000000001111111111111111111111111111111000000000
00000000011111111111111111111111111111111100000000
00000000111111111111111111111111111111111110000000
00000001111111111111111111111111111111111111000000
00000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000
00000111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000
00001111111111111111111111101111111111111111111000
00001111111111100111111111000111111111111111111000
00001111111111000111111111000111111111111111111000
00011111111111000111111110000111111111111111111100
00011111111111000111111110001111111111111111111100
00011111111111101111111111011111111111111111111100
00011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00011110011111111111111111111111111111011111111100
00011110011111111111111111111111111111001111111100
00001111101111111111111111111111111110011111111000
00001111110111111111111111111111111101111111111000
00000111111011111111111111111111111011111111110000
00000111111100111111111111111111110111111111110000
00000011111110011111111111111111001111111111100000
00000011111111100111111111111110111111111111100000
00000001111111111001111111111001111111111111000000
00000000111111111110000000001111111111111110000000
00000000011111111111111111111111111111111100000000
00000000001111111111111111111111111111111000000000
00000000000111111111111111111111111111110000000000
00000000000011111111111111111111111111100000000000
00000000000000111111111111111111111110000000000000
00000000000000011111111111111111111100000000000000
00000000000000000011111111111111100000000000000000
00000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```